# Firebase FCM doesn't send image notification after uploading to Firebase storage

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-storage

I have uploaded an image from the user gallery to Firebase storage and got the following URL -

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tnn-1mddev.appspot.com/o/notificationImages?alt=media&token=9a91bfe6-ae7a-4560-9f42-0adbd49de2e9

which when opening at google chrome is a valid image URL.

The thing is that when I am trying to sent it to the Firebase server at the following method is does not work with my URL from firebase -

```
exports.helperPromiseNotify = function (profileId, notificationKey, body, payloadData, image) {
    // admin
    const fcm = admin.messaging();
    const db = admin.database();

    // prepare obj
    const notificationDBObj = {
        created_at: internalGetUnixEpoch(),
        is_read: false,
        key: notificationKey,
        body: body,
        data: payloadData,  
    };

    console.log("utils.js helperPromiseNotify " + image)
    var payload = {
        notification: {
            body: body,
            image: image
          //this is the place ->  //image: "https://1mdtalent.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/cropped-1-2.png" // <- this is the place 
        },
        data: payloadData
    };

    // find
    const prFetchDeviceTokens = db.ref(config.ENTITY_NAME_DEVICES).child(profileId).child("tokens")
        .once("value")
        .then(snapshot => {
            const tokensArr = new Array();
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                // extract tokens
                const obj = snapshot.val();
                Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
                    tokensArr.push(obj[key]);
                })
            }

            return tokensArr;
        })
    const prSendFCM = tokensArr => {
        if (tokensArr !== undefined && tokensArr !== null && tokensArr.length > 0 && tokensArr.length <=1000) {
            fcm.sendToDevice(tokensArr, payload)
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(`Failed send notification to device: ${error}`);
            });
        }
    };

    // chains
    const prDB = db.ref(config.ENTITY_NAME_NOTIFICATIONS).child(profileId).push(notificationDBObj);
    return prDB
        .then(() => prFetchDeviceTokens)
        .then(tokensArr => prSendFCM(tokensArr));
}
```

I have that other image that I have taken from google which has a cleaner URL and an extension to it, so I guess that is the problem. When switching the "image" variable from the one that is currently running to the one in comment it works, meaning it not a logic problem but a URL problem which the Firebase servers can't work with it

I am trying to figure out what is that the firebase API really expects, and what does my URL from Firebase missing and how can I add it to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update October 2020**

The `admin.messaging.Notification` API has been updated with an [`imageURL` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.notification.md#notificationimageurl).

---

**Original answer**

The Admin SDK is not capable for sending images.

There is no `image` property in the payload. Only `body` & `title`:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.notification.md#notification_interface

**Possible solution:** Try invoking the HTTP API for FCM instead of calling the `sendToDevices` function.

Comment: the link to the documentation seems to be outdated

Answer (score 0):

There us a limit of a few hundread KB's of image size you can sent per notification - check how big is the image you are sending